# Cant parse boto3 client json response using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

i am new in **Python** language. I need to get all **Amazon-Web-Services Identity and Access Management (Amazon-IAM)** policy details using **Boto 3** and **Python**.

I tried to parse **JSON** output from **Boto 3** client and also need to save `key-value` pair into a map (policyName, Arn). Sample **JSON** output is like this:

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
            'content-length': '19143',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'date': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2017 06:39:25 GMT'
        }
    },
    u 'Books': [ {
        u 'PolicyName': 'book1',
        u 'Arn': '002dfgdfgdfgdfgvdfxgdfgdfgdfgfdg',
        u 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 22, 13, 10, 55, tzinfo = tzutc()),
        u 'UpdateDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 22, 13, 10, 55, tzinfo = tzutc())
    }, {
        u 'PolicyName': 'book2','
        u 'Arn': '002dfgdfgdfgdfgvdfxgdfgdfgdfgfdg',
        u 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 22, 13, 10, 55, tzinfo = tzutc()),
        u 'UpdateDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 22, 13, 10, 55, tzinfo = tzutc())
    }]
}
```

I have following code

```
iampolicylist_response = iamClient.list_policies(
    Scope='Local',
    MaxItems=150
)
    print iampolicylist_response
    res=json.dumps(iampolicylist_response)
print res
ret={}
for i in res["PolicyName"]:
  ret[i["PolicyName"]]=i["Arn"]
return ret
```

Using `json.loads`, it shows error like this

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Using `json.dumps`, it shows error like this

> TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 22, 13, 10, 55, tzinfo=tzutc()) is not JSON serializable

What is actual issue?

Comment: res=json.dumps(iampolicylist_response) will convert the object to json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result `iampolicylist_response` is already a dictionary

You do not need to parse it .

See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_policies

The response is a dictionary object

Remove     `res=json.dumps(iampolicylist_response)`